# How can I use two different opacity values on one shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

I want to have a circle with a border of opacity 80% and the fill should be 40%. How can I achieve this within one layer?

As far as I know I can change the opacity of the layer but that changes the opacity of the whole layer.

Answer (score 1):

Having the circle shape with the stroke aligned outside in just one layer:

[image: Circle]

[image]

- From the **Layers Panel** > Activate the *Shape Layer* > Click the **Mask Icon** at the bottom [image: Mask Icon] to create a Mask
- Holding on <kbd>Cmd</kbd> (Mac)/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (Win) > Click the *Shape Layer* icon to load the selection and fill the mask with 60% Black, this will give as a result a 40% opacity in the layer

[image: 60black]

- Using the same selection > **Menu Select** > **Inverse** > fill the mask with 80% Black, this will give as a result a 20% opacity in the layer

[image: MAsk]

**Result**

[image: Result]

[image: Color]

Answer (score 1):

### Fill and Opacity to Fade Colours in Photoshop

It's not ideal and something Adobe should address, but you can do this. It's ultra simple, but can be a little tricky if you need exact values.

---

1. Create your shape
2. select the colours you require
3. Now you just have to adjust the opacity and fill values as shown in the images below.

---

In the first example, I've set the Opacity value to `65%` and the Fill value to `40%`.

In the second example, I've set the Opacity value to `100%` and the Fill value to `30%`.

---

### Non-Destructive & Ajustable

The advantage of doing it this way is, it's **non-destructive** and easy to adjust.

[image]

[image]

[image]

### The Separate Layer way

If you want to have the Border with Opacity but not the Fill area, you'll have to have them as separate layers as seen in the last example, where the Fill value is `100%` Fill and Opacity and the Border is `25%` Opacity with `100%` Fill

[image]

### The Layer Style Way

And the final way, which can be the best way, is to create your Border as a Stroke in **Layer Styles**.

This is a good way to do it. However, the Stroke that is created often has strange shaping on some shapes, so it will not be the best solution in some circumstances.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Duplicate the layer.
2. Make layer 1 only fill with opacity you want
3. Make layer 2 only with line and opacity you want.